# update table when php statement results file = 1

Tags: php, android, mysql

i m running php file with select stmt. if reslut == 1 : run the second stmt. if not - don't run it. the problem is that second stmt run only if i set : if(mysqli_num_rows($statement) == 0 : but - the first stmt result is not 0 ...i m enable to login to my android application- means row found... )

here is my code :

```
 <?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx");

$groupname= $_POST["groupname"];
$grouppassword= $_POST["grouppassword"];
$loggedInUser= $_POST["loggedInUser"];

 $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM MGroup WHERE group_name= ? AND group_password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $groupname, $grouppassword);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $groupID, $groupname, $grouppassword, $group_owner);

$group= array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $group["groupname"]=$groupname;
    $group["grouppassword"]=$grouppassword;
    $group["group_owner"]=$group_owner;   

}
echo json_encode($group);

//update logged-in user with his current group - its is not necessary the group owner

if(mysqli_num_rows($statement) == 1)  {
$statement= mysqli_prepare($con,"UPDATE User SET group_code = (SELECT group_id FROM MGroup WHERE group_name = ? ) WHERE username= ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$groupname,$loggedInUser);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

}

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx"); edit this in your question

Comment: but its password and stuff...my private hosting details..

Comment: ok...i solved it by changing : if(mysqli_num_rows($statement) == 1) to if($group)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to just take a count of the $group array. Kinda simple but it would work as well.

```
if(count($group) == 1)
```

Comment: True. I overlooked it. You're only populating it with one row.